# keras predict_generator output shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I was using `keras` with `TensorFlow` backend to do binary image classification (I used sigmoid activation function for the final layer). After I trained the model, I tried to use `predict_generator` to make predictions on a new set of 412 images:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory("E:\\Projects\\Images\\", 
                                                  target_size = (150, 150), 
                                                  class_mode = None, 
                                                  shuffle = False)
test_generator.reset()
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, verbose = 1, steps = 412/16)
```

However, the output shape is strange (824 X 1). I wonder why the output is not 412 X 1 (or (412 X 2)), and how I can interpret this result.

```
pred.shape
(824, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess...

You are asking for steps=412/16 ( that is 25.75 steps ).
25.75 * batch_size=32 = 824

My best guess is that you are assuming that the ImageDataGenerator batch size is 16 (I'm assuming that where the steps denominator comes from) while it is in reality 32.

Comment: Your guess would be very correct...and I feel like a fool right now! :-/